# Issue in multiple cursors in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table tbLicence with four feilds

- AgentId
- LicenceNumber
- LineOfAuthority
- Jurisdiction

Let us say I have one record with the following values

- AgentId = 307
- LicenceNumber = 245678
- LineOfAuthority = "Dental Services, Personal Lines, Casualty"
- Jurisdiction = "Alabama, New York"

...

...

Similarily I have other records with different values in this table

Note that LineOfAuthority and Jurisdiction contain multiple values seperated by comma ','.

If I will pass parameters as

- @AgentId = 307
- @LineOfAuthority ="Casualty"
- @Jurisdiction = "New York"

Then output should be

LicenceNumber = 245678

I have stored procedure as below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prLicenceFetchForAgentId]  

@LineOfAuthority nvarchar(max),
@Jurisdiction nvarchar(max),
@AgentId int

AS
Create table #tbLOA (
LOA nvarchar(max)
);

create table #tbtempJuris(
Jurisdiction nvarchar(max)
);

Insert into #tbLOA(LOA) Select LineOfAuthority from tbLicence where AgentId =@AgentId;
Insert into #tbtempJuris(Jurisdiction) Select Jurisdiction from tbLicence where AgentId =@AgentId;

DECLARE @LOASubString varchar(100);
DECLARE @JurisdictionSubString varchar(100);

-- first cursor

DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
Select LOA FROM #tbLOA
OPEN @MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
INTO @LOASubString  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
-- second cursor

DECLARE @MyCursor2 CURSOR
SET @MyCursor2 = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
Select LOA FROM #tbLOA
OPEN @MyCursor2
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor2
INTO @JurisdictionSubString  

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
 --second code

 if(@LOASubString = @LineOfAuthority and @JurisdictionSubString = @Jurisdiction)
 begin
 Select LicenceNumber from tbLicence where LineOfAuthority = @LOASubString
 and Jurisdiction=@JurisdictionSubString and AgentId =@AgentId;
 break;
 end

 FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor2
 INTO @JurisdictionSubString

 END

 CLOSE @MyCursor2
 DEALLOCATE @MyCursor2

 --end cursor 2

 FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
 INTO @LOASubString

 END

CLOSE @MyCursor
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor
```

Now I am not able to get the proper result... It's not showing any Licence Number...
Please Help me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, having **multiple values** in a single column is **against** first normal form of database design and **should be avoided** at all costs!

Second, I don't understand what on earth you are doing with two nested cursors?!?!?!?

This seems like a really simple, single `SELECT` statement:

```
 SELECT
     LicenceNumber 
 FROM 
     dbo.tbLicence 
 WHERE
     AgentId = @AgentId
     AND LineOfAuthority LIKE '%' + @LineOfAuthority + '%'
     AND Jurisdiction = LIKE '%' + @Jurisdiction + '%';
```

Comment: You are absolutely right sir... Actually the idea of having multiple values in single column was not my idea. It was done by other devoleper... Thanks a lot sir...